# What progress is being made on $NP \cap coNP$ having complete problems?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, open-problem

I'm very curious about this and have a proof sketch that it does not in the answers below. The reasons I'm currently thinking about this is because of the new paper on the class $PTFNP$ which can be downloaded [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/056/download/).

Comment: Assuming that $P = NP$, $NP \cap coNP = P$ and thus has complete problems. Thus my proof used diagonalization to show that $P \neq NP$, so it really must be wrong. I would love to know why.

Comment: Is it possible that no encoding of first order reductions like this exists? I find that incredibly difficult to believe...

Comment: The FO part isn't the issue. The issue is where you say "Clearly we have that $D \in NP \cap coNP$." "Clearly" should always be the first place you look for a hole in a proof you think has a hole :), and indeed there is one here. Ask yourself: what is the running time of $f_i$? Unfortunately, though the question was asked earnestly by someone who knows what they're talking about, this turns out to not be a research-level question...

Comment: Errr each $f_i$ is a first order reduction so they can run in logarithmic space, and $L$ is in $coNP \cap NP$, so I feel like that is actually clear. Unless the encoding $i \mapsto f_i$ cannot be efficiently computed for some reason or another.

Comment: Ahhh right, so calling these reductions is probably not the best terminology, really these are just potential reductions, first order queries between string structures. Maybe it would make more sense if I used logspace reductions instead, as then it would just be an enumeration of logspace machines instead.

Comment: Unless what you're saying has another implication that I'm not seeing here? I think it stemmed from my bad terminology.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. Indeed, each f_i takes c_i log(n) space to compute. But unless I'm mistaken, the c_i are not bounded by a universal constant c, so the machine which on input $i$ runs a logspace machine for $f_i(i)$ uses more than log space... This applies even more so if you enumerate over logspace reductions.

Comment: Ay, there's the rub

Comment: With some thinking I may be able to get out of this or show conclusively that it is a problem in the $FO$ case, but it certainly is not alright a priori

Comment: Gave it a go, they're unbounded and you lose massive chunks of FO if you try to make it not so

Comment: Can you prove unconditionally that FO w/ $k$ quantifiers can't be computed in $(k-1)\log n$ space? That'd be the first place I'd look...

Comment: I’m voting to close as off-topic. This site is not meant to serve as a vetting place for alleged proofs.

Comment: Yeah that's my bad, go for it

Comment: I've edited this so that it is a true question with motivation and placed my alleged proof in the answers.

Comment: 1. Please don't edit the question to radically change its meaning.  At that point it would be better to delete this question and ask a new one.    2. The updated question is probably too broad.  What research have you done?  Have you done a literature search?  See the 'Questions should be based on..' section of our [help/on-topic].  3. Please don't use answers to post an alleged proof that you're hoping someone will vet for you.

Comment: Okay, I apologize. Will be more careful when posting again.